# Name of javascript class ExtJS subclass

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hi I have an ext Subclass.  If I create an instance of it in the chrome console:

```
morris = new mo.panel.myPanel()
```

I get the object that I can inspect:

```
mo.panel.myPanel.Ext.extend.constructor {
    name: "TheName",
    aBtn: mo.lite.Button.Ext.extend.constructor,
    historyGrid: mo.lite.Grid.Ext.extend.constructor,
    disabled: false,
    hidden: false…
}
```

How can I get the string `mo.panel.myPanel.Ext.extend.constructor`

I have tried `morris.constructor.name` but this just prints out `''`

If I call `morris.constructor.toString();` it prints the constructor function but not the custom class name.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Morris

Comment: Have you tried using `$className`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$className`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Base-property-S-className):

```
morris.$className
```